# Different page titles with one header file?

Tags: php

How do you do multiple page titles with on header file? Theres one thing though. For the index page, i've got

```
error_reporting(0);
if ($_GET["error"]=="404") { 
    include("forum/styles/art_air/web_template/overall_header.php");
    include("include/404"); 
    include("include/index");
    include("forum/styles/art_air/web_template/overall_footer.php");
} else { 
    include("forum/styles/art_air/web_template/overall_header.php");
    include("include/index");
    include("forum/styles/art_air/web_template/overall_footer.php");
}
```

So i would have the header before anything else. So how would i manage to make so that

`index?error=404` and index have different titles? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on how you set the title in the header file. Generally you can imagine the include command as if it copies the code from the header and all other files over for the execution. So if you set a title variable before including the header it is used in there with that very value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript and `document.title`.

Example:

```
<script language="javascript">document.title = "My Title"</script>
```

JS can be used in body.

---

Another method is to set a `$GLOBAL` variable before including everything.

Example:

```
error_reporting(0);
$GLOBALS['404'] = 0;
if ($_GET["error"]=="404") { 
    $GLOBALS['404'] = 1;
    include("forum/styles/art_air/web_template/overall_header.php");
    include("include/404"); 
    include("include/index");
    include("forum/styles/art_air/web_template/overall_footer.php");
} else { 
    $GLOBALS['404'] = 0;
    include("forum/styles/art_air/web_template/overall_header.php");
    include("include/index");
    include("forum/styles/art_air/web_template/overall_footer.php");
}
```

In your `overall_header.php`:

```
if($GLOBALS['404'] == 1) echo '<title>404: Not Found</title>';
else echo '<title>My Title</title>';
```

Comment: Your javascript seems to be alot easier to use, so i will probably be using that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In `overall_header.php`

```
<?php
$title = "Hello, wolrd!";
if ( $_GET["error"] == "404" ) {
    $title = "Error";
}
?>

<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a switch

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
switch($page) {
    case "index.php":
        echo "<title>My Homepage</title>";
        break;
    case "apples.php":
        echo "<title>The Best Apples!</title>";
        break;
    case "bananas.php":
        echo "<title>We Sell Bananas</title>";
        break;
}
?>
```